# LibVLC/VLC Unity Android Compilation Issue

Tags: libvlc, vlc-android, vlc-unity

I am trying to compile the VLC Unity plugin for Android, which requires vlc-android to generate libvlc first, but have been running into an issue where a Vulkan beta header is not found.

Essentially, I've been following the CI pipeline [here](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-unity/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) using the specified Docker image (`registry.videolan.org/vlc-debian-android:20230614051113`) at the `.libvlc-android-common` stage.

Currently I'm trying to build for arm64-v8a, and at the step `ANDROID_HOME=/sdk/android-sdk-linux ./buildsystem/compile.sh -l -b -r -a ${ANDROID_ABI}`, it runs for a long while before finally throwing out an error due to a missing Vulkan header.

```
In file included from src/libavutil/hwcontext_vulkan.c:39:
In file included from src/libavutil/hwcontext_vulkan.h:25:
/sdk/android-ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/vulkan/vulkan.h:89:10: fatal error: 'vulkan_beta.h' file not found
#include "vulkan_beta.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [/vlc-unity/vlc-android/libvlcjni/vlc/contrib/contrib-android-aarch64-linux-android/ffmpeg/ffbuild/common.mak:81: libavutil/hwcontext_vulkan.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/vlc-unity/vlc-android/libvlcjni/vlc/contrib/contrib-android-aarch64-linux-android/ffmpeg/vlc_build'
make: *** [../src/ffmpeg/rules.mak:237: .ffmpeg] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/vlc-unity/vlc-android/libvlcjni/vlc/contrib/contrib-android-aarch64-linux-android'
```

I'm a bit stumped as to how to proceed. I'd have assumed since I am using the same build environment (the Docker image) as the CI pipeline, then the build would be successful, but I keep having this issue. If anyone knows what the solution might be, it'd be greatly appreciated.